# Selecting Parent JSON data that will automatically display the Child data

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have two different JSON data file in this format: `risk.json` and `class.json`.
I wanted a dropdown list for all `Description` coming from `risk.json` and once I clicked on any of the dropdown list it will automatically select the `riskType` field from `class.json` file.

```
risk.json

[
    {
      "riskType":"creditRisk",
      "Desciption":"Credit Risk",
      "detail":"memo field",
      "recordDate":"20200603",
      "recordTime":"10:30:40",
      "operator":"adroit",
      "operation":"edit",
      "workstation":"11.20.10.1",
      "recordCounter":"1"
      },
    {
      "riskType":"marketRisk",
      "Description":"Market Risk",
      "detail":"memo field",
      "recordDate":"20200603",
      "recordTime":"10:30:40",
      "operator":"adroit",
      "operation":"edit",
      "workstation":"11.20.10.1",
      "recordCounter":"1"
      },
    {
      "riskType":"opertioanlRisk",
      "Description":"Operational Risk",
      "detail":"memo field",
      "recordDate":"20200603",
      "recordTime":"10:30:40",
      "operator":"adroit",
      "operation":"edit",
      "workstation":"11.20.10.1",
      "recordCounter":"1"
      },
    {
      "riskType":"liquidityRisk",
      "Description":"Liquidity Risk",
      "detail":"memo field",
      "recordDate":"20200603",
      "recordTime":"10:30:40",
      "operator":"adroit",
      "operation":"edit",
      "workstation":"11.20.10.1",
      "recordCounter":"1"
      },
      {
      "riskType":"legalRisk",
      "Description":"Legal Risk",
      "detail":"memo field",
      "recordDate":"20200603",
      "recordTime":"10:30:40",
      "operator":"adroit",
      "operation":"edit",
      "workstation":"11.20.10.1",
      "recordCounter":"1"
      }
  ]

class.json
[
    {
      "classId":"fraudRisk",
      "Description":"Fraud Risk",
      "riskType": "Credit Risk",
      "detail":"memo field",
      "recordDate":"20200603",
      "recordTime":"10:30:40",
      "operator":"adroit",
      "operation":"edit",
      "workstation":"11.20.10.1",
      "recordCounter":"1"
      },
    {
      "classId":"creditEvent",
      "Description":"Credit Event",
      "riskType": "Market Risk",
      "detail":"memo field",
      "recordDate":"20200603",
      "recordTime":"10:30:40",
      "operator":"adroit",
      "operation":"edit",
      "workstation":"11.20.10.1",
      "recordCounter":"1"
      }
  ]
```

Your contribution will very helpful

Comment: Hi, the risk,json "description" field and the content of class.json "riskType" field seem to be equal, is a mapping even nessecary ?

Comment: yes,mapping is neccessary